# How to reset the Kafka offset in Franz-go based on the timestamp?

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I reset the Kafka based on relative offset using `kmsg.NewOffsetCommitRequest()` with no issue.
I can't find any solution to reset the offset using `timestamp`

I can reset Kafka like this via the command line:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group platform-dev --reset-offsets --to-datetime 2022-03-30T01:01:01.001 --topic develop --execute
```

Does anyone know any franz-go API that I can use to achieve this? or document or sample implementation?